# Can I add a string to the end of an href?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a random quote generator for FreeCodeCamp I need help making the tweet button work. My quotes are stored as strings in a an array. Is there away to add them on to the end of my href like this: href='http://twitter.com/home/?status=string ?

http://codepen.io/tyl-er/pen/KrjWVA?editors=1000

```
<head>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/41c0e08ce5.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="flip">
    <div onclick="randomIndex" class="card">
        <div class="face front">
            <!--logo here-->
        </div>
        <div class="face back">

            <textarea rows="10" cols="30" type=text id="mytext"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="div10">
    <p>(Spoliers maybe ¯\_(ツ)_/¯) <del>Written</del> and coded by Tyler Pelzer</p>
    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter" target="blank" href='http://twitter.com/home/?status=Twitter is like the lunch meeting with potential clients before you do the pitch. via @blogtyrant'>
        <span class="fa fa-twitter"></span>
    </a>
</div>


$('.flip').click(function printquote(){

var strings = []; // <--superlong array of quotes
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * strings.length);
var randomString = strings[randomIndex];
document.getElementById("mytext").value = randomString;
//that was easy^

});

$('.flip').click(function(){
        $(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped').mouseleave(function()
        {
            $(this).removeClass('flipped');

        });
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Mind giving string examples rather than a empty array? In the case of `http://twitter.com/home/?status=string` is the string just `string` or is it `status=string`? If it's just `string` where are the keys defined for many array values?

Comment: It's a bunch of mostly longish quotes like this "By love you mean big lightning bolts to the heart, where you can't eat and you can't work, and you just run off and get married and make babies. The reason you haven't felt it is because it doesn't exist. What you call love was invented by guys like me...to sell nylons. - Don"

I just shortened because it's a very long array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set href attributes much the same way as you have set the textarea's value. Add an ID on the link tag and:

```
document.getElementById('twitterLink').href = 'https://twitter.com/home?status=' + encodeURIComponent(randomString);
```

Edit: as you would like to do this separately to your flip click handler, let's refactor the following code:

```
$('.flip').click(function printquote(){
    var strings = []; // <--superlong array of quotes
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * strings.length); 
    var randomString = strings[randomIndex];
    document.getElementById("mytext").value = randomString;
    //that was easy^
});
```

Into this:

```
function getQuotes() {
    return []; // <--superlong array of quotes
}

function getRandomEntry(entries) {
    return entries[Math.floor(Math.random() * entries.length)];
}

$('.flip').click(function printquote(){
    document.getElementById("mytext").value = getRandomEntry(getQuotes());
    //that was easy^
});
```

That way you can share functionality to get the random quote with this new code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var randomQuote = getRandomEntry(getQuotes());
    document.getElementById('twitterLink').href = 'https://twitter.com/home?status=' + encodeURIComponent(randomQuote);
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks I was trying to use getElementByhref, but I just made that up so it  wasn't very successful lol. What should my href =?

Comment: The answer has something that you can place within the click handler for .flip, underneath `that was easy` :)

Comment: I just want .flip to flip the card. I have a separate bootstrap button for the twitter link. I tried doing this, but it didn't work. 

$('#twitterLink').click(function() {
 document.getElementById('twitterLink').href = 'https://twitter.com/home?status=' + encodeURIComponent(randomString);
};

Comment: @tyl-er I've updated my answer to update the Twitter link when the page loads. I've also refactored the code a bit so the random quote selection logic is not repeated. Feel free to adapt it and ask if you get stuck in using it.

Comment: Dude you're awesome. I actually a lot from that answer.

Comment: Keep on coding, you'll be even more awesome soon :)